# How to print the line after execlp system call

Tags: c, operating-system, exec

I know that when execlp system call executed successfully it will not return back to the calling process. Is there any way to make a return and print the line after the call to execlp.

```
int main() 
{ 
    pid_t pid;
    /* fork a child process */ 
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    { 
        /* error occurred */ 
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed"); 
        return 1; 
    } 
    else if (pid == 0) 
    { 
        /* child process */ 
        execlp("/bin/ls","ls", "-lrth", NULL); 
        printf("In Child after execlp call\n"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        /* parent process */ 
        /* parent will wait for the child to complete */ 
        wait(NULL); 
        printf("Child Complete"); 
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to see the print "In Child after execlp call".
How to make it happen.

Comment: AFAIK, unless execlp fail, there is no way that this printf to be reached.

Comment: The `exec` family replace the current process with the new executable image. Upon successful execution of the `execlp`, whatever follows no longer exists. The child is completely replaced. That's the point of `fork`ing; so that the new program can be started without replacing the existing program.

Comment: btw, never use `NULL` as the last pointer argument of a variadic function; always convert it to the expected type (eg. `(char*)0` or (void*)0`). `NULL` can be defined as simply `0`, in which case an `int` shorter than a pointer will be passed.

Comment: No, you can't do this, and you've stated the reason why:  because when the `execlp` system call executes successfully, it will not return back to the calling process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding:

```
execlp("/bin/ls","ls", "-lrth", NULL); 
printf("In Child after execlp call\n");
```

The function: `execlp()` never returns, if successful.  Also, the child process no longer exists when (in this case) the `ls` exits.

So the correct thing to do would be handling the case where the call to `execlp()` fails.  In the case of failure the correct code would be:

```
perror( "execlp failed" );
exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
```

Note: the call to `perror()` outputs your error message AND the reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`